# Intellij no me detecta anotaciones de spring como @Query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

estoy empezando a usar **intellij**  para usar spring pero por el momento no me esta detectando la anotacion `@Query`

```
package models.dao;

import models.entity.Usuario;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

public interface IUsuarioDao extends CrudRepository<Usuario,Long> {

    @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.email = ?1 and u.password = ?2")
    Usuario findByEmailandPassword(String email, String password);

    @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.usuario = ?1 and u.password = ?2")
    Usuario findByUserandPassword(String user, String password);

}
```

El `import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;`  lo he puesto forzado a mano a ver si me detectaba el `@Query` pero no asi. Me creia que era mas fluido este IDE. Aver si me podeis echar una mano. Mil gracias.

Si tambien sabeis de buenos plugins de spring para intellij os lo agradeceria, aunque ya tengo varios instlaados y no veo que sirvan de mucho.

Comment: Hola, ¿alguna razón particular para usar ***intelij***? Yo uso Atom y VS Code y los plugins de Spring son bastante buenos. Claro, es sólo mi opinión. Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras, yo pensaba hacerlo con ese IDE. Pero [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267135/visual-studio-code-spring-boot-como-mapear-mi-bd-creada-en-wamp?noredirect=1#comment492615_267135) puedes ver la discusion que tuve con un usuario que me aconsejo **intellij** . Un saludo.

Comment: Como dije, es cuestión de gustos. Normalmente cuando se piensa en Java la gente se va a *Intelij* o *Netbeans* o incluso a *Eclipse*. En mi caso, por tema de recursos, uso VS Code y Atom. Tal vez *Intelij* tenga cosas específicas para el desarrollo en Java, pero en mi caso puede llegar a ser extremadamente pesado para un proyecto MVC sencillo. Usando el *starter* de Spring.io y eligiendo la tecnología deseada (*maven o gradle*) puedes tener un esqueleto de aplicación en segundos. El IDE entonces es a gusto del desarrollador.

Comment: me he pasado a VSCODE de nuevo porque me estaba dando problemas con cosas tan simple como la de @Query, voy a ver si aqui no me dan problemas. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @MauricioContreras pero por qué consideras que el ide y el editor son excluyentes? yo uso vscode para ediciones rápidas e intellij cuando necesita funcionas pesadas del ide como puede ser decompilar librerias o depurar...
te puedo asegurar que no he tenido ni el más mínimo problema usando esa etiqueta con intellij ni con vscode y la falta de fluidez diría que es por falta de control del ide, con alt+enter dentro de tu etiqueta puedes añadir el import automáticamente o configurar el ide para que se añada solo lo que no funciona en ningún editor que yo sepa, saludos!

Comment: @Blazerg, no lo considero excluyente. Yo usaría un maravilloso IDE como *Intellij*, pero como ya dije, no tengo recursos suficientes para ello (me refiero a recursos de hardware). Además, mi fuerte no es Java, al menos por ahora. Es por ello que tal vez mis preferencias se vean condicionadas por el lenguaje que uso y por los recursos que dispongo. Tal vez no me expliqué bien. Mi intención no es desaconsejar un IDE en favor de un editor o lo contrario. Creo que debí expresarme mejor al decir que yo lograba una funcionalidad parecida y aceptable con un editor. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El intellij no te detecta el @Query, al igual que no lo hará ningún editor de texto porque no estás usando la anotación correcta (que no es `import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;`)

Esta anotación no sé de dónde la has sacado pero el @Query corresponde con la etiqueta `import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` o eso intuyo puesto que hay varios @Query. En cualquier caso, intellij nunca te ha fallado, te ha devuelto un error porque no has añadido la librería correspondiente, en estos casos en intellij puedes usar alt+enter pulsando en la etiqueta y el propio ide te devuelve una lista de los posibles imports para que añadas el que tú quieras.

A la segunda pregunta añado que intellij está 100% preparado para utilizar aplicaciones spring-boot. Al contrario que en los editores tipo VS code, no necesitas ningún plugin adicional.

Comment: Ya me di cuenta. Muchas gracias. La verdad que he vuelto a VSCode y me facilita mas las cosas que intellij.

Comment: eso ya como veas, yo te digo que no veo al editor y al ide excluyentes, creo que se pueden usar los dos perfectamente. En tu caso yo te recomendaría mirar algún vídeo sobre las "key features" de intellij para que veas lo que te aporta el ide, en cualquier caso si la respuesta soluciona tu problema te agradecerías que la marcaras como válida, saludos!!

Answer (score -2):

La solución podría estar dada, al menos a mi, me funcionó.
ir a:
settings >> Build , Executions...>>>Build tools>>>Maven y ahí indican donde está el ejecutable del maven que usan para sus proyectos.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOizW.png): [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]